# How to raise timeout error in unittesting

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testing

This is first time i am touching ruby, so no sure about correct terminology. I have tried searching for mulitple things, but couldn't find a solution.

I have this code block

```rb
domain_response = MyDomain::Api::MyApi::Api.new(parameters: message.to_domain_object, timeout: 1000)
# :nocov:
case (response = domain_response.response)
when MyDomain::Api::MyApi::SuccessResponse
  ## do something
when Domain::ErrorResponses::TimeoutResponse
  ## do something.
```

now i am trying to testing `TimeoutResponse`, I have written(tried) this

```rb
      it "when api call timesout" do
        expect(MyDomain::Api::MyApi::Api).to{
          receive(:new)
        } raise_error(MyDomain::ErrorResponses::TimeoutResponse)
      end
```

this gave me error that unexpected identifier.

I have also tried by not providing `receive`, and it gave me error that `block is expected`.

Whats the proper way to raise an error that i can test?

Update:

Here is where i am stuck now

```rb
      it "when api call timesout" do
        # 1
        expect(MyDomain::Api::MyApi::Api).to(
          receive(:new),
        ).and_return(domain_api_instance)
        
        # 2
        expect(domain_api_instance.response).to receive(:response).and_raise(Domain::ErrorResponses::TimeoutResponse)

        expect(domain_api_instance.response).to eq(ApiError::Timeout)
end
```

But with this code i am getting this error

```sh
  1) Rpc::Package::SubPackage::V1::PackageService#first_test testing when api call timesout
     Failure/Error: expect(domain_api_instance.response).to receive(:response).and_raise(Domain::ErrorResponses::TimeoutResponse)
       #<InstanceDouble(MyDomain::Api::MyApi::Api) (anonymous)> received unexpected message :response with (no args)
```

Comment: I appreciate you have abstracted some details, but more information on what those namespaces represent would be helpful

Comment: yeah, as i said, i am new to ruby so not sure what details are relevant and how to abstract them away. ... i believe the namespaces are just the packages here (java term?). none of them are serving any other purpose except organizing those classes in it.

Comment: @bashford7 updated the question

Comment: I think your first attempt will fix the syntax error if you do `).and raise_error` instead of `) raise_error` ... rspec DSL can be a bit tricky at first, but it's actually just chained method calls ...